# samsung galaxy watch 3 (Tizen) connect with android studio

Tags: android-studio, adb, tizen, samsung-galaxy-watch

I have samsung galaxy watch 3  with Tizen version 5.5.0.2.  It has wireless charger and  no usb port. I tried to connect with the help of wifi adb but it has no option like debug over wifi .The question is how to connect it with android studio?[Watch Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0TyH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't Galaxy Watch 3 using Tizen instead of Wear OS?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Watch_3

This probably means using the Tizen developer tools https://developer.tizen.org/

Comment: Sorry I was not aware of Tizen.  It has  "Tizen version 5.5.0.2" ,"Knox Tizen Wearable SDK 2.5.0"  &  "SE for Tizen 2.0.0".   Will I be able to connect it with android studio?

Comment: probably https://developer.tizen.org/

Comment: Last year, Samsung changed OS for Gear Watch series from Tizen to Android Wear. For Tizen, you can use Tizen Studio.